# How to disable local history feature in NetBeans IDE 7.1?

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-7

NetBeans IDE has a built-in local history feature which creates a thousands of files in `C:\Users\USER\.netbeans\7.1\var\filehistory` (Windows path). Is there any way to disable this feature?

I've found *Cleanup Local History files after* option but i don't know if setting it to 0 will disable local history. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a plugin:

Tools -> Plugins -> Installed -> Choose "Local History", then click "Deactivate".

[image]

Comment: Thanks. After disabling it can i safety delete `C:\Users\USER\.netbeans\7.1\var\filehistory`?